# How can I send an HTTP request to my router with a not well-formatted field?

Tags: html, http, curl, tcp, wget

I'm trying to find a way to enable/disable my router whithout the need for manually using the browser. After a bit of snooping, it seems to me that I have to send a request like that [from WireShark]:

```
0000   9c 97 26 c9 c2 20 b0 48 7a 80 52 9c 08 00 45 00  ..&.. .Hz.R...E.
0010   02 2e 28 89 40 00 80 06 00 00 c0 a8 00 02 c0 a8  ..(.@...........
0020   00 01 d6 a8 00 50 34 fd c9 8d c9 ef dd 2d 50 18  .....P4......-P.
0030   fe da 83 74 00 00 50 4f 53 54 20 2f 77 61 6e 53  ...t..POST /wanS
0040   74 61 74 75 73 2e 6c 70 20 48 54 54 50 2f 31 2e  tatus.lp HTTP/1.
0050   31 0d 0a 48 6f 73 74 3a 20 31 39 32 2e 31 36 38  1..Host: 192.168
0060   2e 30 2e 31 0d 0a 55 73 65 72 2d 41 67 65 6e 74  .0.1..User-Agent
0070   3a 20 4d 6f 7a 69 6c 6c 61 2f 35 2e 30 20 28 57  : Mozilla/5.0 (W
0080   69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 4e 54 20 36 2e 31 3b 20 57  indows NT 6.1; W
0090   4f 57 36 34 3b 20 72 76 3a 33 36 2e 30 29 20 47  OW64; rv:36.0) G
00a0   65 63 6b 6f 2f 32 30 31 30 30 31 30 31 20 46 69  ecko/20100101 Fi
00b0   72 65 66 6f 78 2f 33 36 2e 30 0d 0a 41 63 63 65  refox/36.0..Acce
00c0   70 74 3a 20 74 65 78 74 2f 68 74 6d 6c 2c 61 70  pt: text/html,ap
00d0   70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f 78 68 74 6d 6c 2b  plication/xhtml+
00e0   78 6d 6c 2c 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f 6e 2f  xml,application/
00f0   78 6d 6c 3b 71 3d 30 2e 39 2c 2a 2f 2a 3b 71 3d  xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=
0100   30 2e 38 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70 74 2d 4c 61 6e 67  0.8..Accept-Lang
0110   75 61 67 65 3a 20 69 74 2d 49 54 2c 69 74 3b 71  uage: it-IT,it;q
0120   3d 30 2e 38 2c 65 6e 2d 55 53 3b 71 3d 30 2e 35  =0.8,en-US;q=0.5
0130   2c 65 6e 3b 71 3d 30 2e 33 0d 0a 41 63 63 65 70  ,en;q=0.3..Accep
0140   74 2d 45 6e 63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3a 20 67 7a 69 70  t-Encoding: gzip
0150   2c 20 64 65 66 6c 61 74 65 0d 0a 44 4e 54 3a 20  , deflate..DNT: 
0160   31 0d 0a 52 65 66 65 72 65 72 3a 20 68 74 74 70  1..Referer: http
0170   3a 2f 2f 31 39 32 2e 31 36 38 2e 30 2e 31 2f 77  ://192.168.0.1/w
0180   61 6e 53 74 61 74 75 73 2e 6c 70 0d 0a 43 6f 6f  anStatus.lp..Coo
0190   6b 69 65 3a 20 78 41 75 74 68 5f 53 45 53 53 49  kie: xAuth_SESSI
01a0   4f 4e 5f 49 44 3d 49 4d 45 74 4f 38 44 4c 45 73  ON_ID=IMEtO8DLEs
01b0   51 70 6d 54 77 69 64 67 43 59 6c 51 41 3d 0d 0a  QpmTwidgCYlQA=..
01c0   43 6f 6e 6e 65 63 74 69 6f 6e 3a 20 6b 65 65 70  Connection: keep
01d0   2d 61 6c 69 76 65 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2d  -alive..Content-
01e0   54 79 70 65 3a 20 61 70 70 6c 69 63 61 74 69 6f  Type: applicatio
01f0   6e 2f 78 2d 77 77 77 2d 66 6f 72 6d 2d 75 72 6c  n/x-www-form-url
0200   65 6e 63 6f 64 65 64 0d 0a 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74  encoded..Content
0210   2d 4c 65 6e 67 74 68 3a 20 32 39 0d 0a 0d 0a 72  -Length: 29....r
0220   6e 3d 49 4d 45 74 4f 38 44 4c 45 73 51 70 6d 54  n=IMEtO8DLEsQpmT
0230   77 69 64 67 43 59 6c 51 41 25 33 44              widgCYlQA%3D
```

As you can see, it ends with **'rn=IMEtO8DLEsQpmTwidgCYlQA%3D'**, that is the session cookie.
Putting a *'normal'* request the router goes back to index instead of performing the action, **probably** for the lack of 'rn=IMEtO8DLEsQpmTwidgCYlQA%3D'.

Until now, I tried using Wget (under windows...) but I can't find a way to add the last info.

So I would know if

- there is a way to add an header that is not header-compliant (use of = instead of : ) using wGet or if
- there is a **tool more suited for that task** (I'm looking for cUrl but I don't think it acts different from wGet).

The batch file (plain ol' DOS) I wrote for testing wGet is:

```
@title %~n0
@cls
@set _wget="C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget"
@set _url=http://192.168.0.1/
@set _urls=http://192.168.0.1/standard.lp
@set _urlw=http://192.168.0.1/wanStatus.lp
@set _post=--post-data="/wanStatus.lp HTTP/1.1"
@set _cook=./cookies.txt
@set _hdr1="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
@set _hdr2="Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
@set _hdr3="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
@set _hdr4="DNT: 1"
@set _agnt="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
@set _rfr="Referer: http://192.168.0.1/wanStatus.lp"
@set _opt=--server-response --timestamping --user-agent=%_agnt% --keep-session-cookies --referer=%_rfr% --save-headers --header=%_hdr1% --header=%_hdr2% --header=%_hdr3% --header=%_hdr4% --debug
%_wget% %_opt% --save-cookies %_cook% %_url%
%_wget% %_opt% --load-cookies %_cook% %_urlw%
@FOR /F "eol=# tokens=1,6,7* delims=    " %%i in (F:\wget\cookies.txt) do @(
   @echo i=%%i j=%%j k=%%k l=%%l
   @set _ckhost=%%i
   @set _ckname=%%j
   @set _ckval=%%k
)
@echo host=%_ckhost%  cookie name=%_ckname%  value=%_ckval%
@if "%_ckname%"=="xAuth_SESSION_ID" set _rn=rn=%_ckval%
@if "%_rn:~-1%"=="=" set _rn=%_rn:~0,-1%%%3D
@echo _rn='%_rn%'
%_wget% %_opt% --load-cookies %_cook% %_post% --header="%_rn%" %_url%
```

but it ends up this way:

```
F:\wget>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget" --server-response --timestamping --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" --keep-session-cookies --referer="Referer: http://192.168.0.1/wanStatus.lp" --save-headers --header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" --header="Accept-Language: it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" --header="DNT: 1" --debug --load-cookies ./cookies.txt --post-data="/wanStatus.lp HTTP/1.1" --header="rn=MGyN4YpepJoE6kSXPVT9lgA%3D" http://192.168.0.1/
SYSTEM_WGETRC = c:/progra~1/wget/etc/wgetrc
syswgetrc = C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32/etc/wgetrc
Setting --load-cookies (loadcookies) to ./cookies.txt
Setting --post-data (postdata) to /wanStatus.lp HTTP/1.1
Setting --header (header) to rn=MGyN4YpepJoE6kSXPVT9lgA%3D
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\wget: --header: intestazione "rn=MGyN4YpepJoE6kSXPVT9lgA%3D" non valida.
```

Thank you **very much** for any suggestion! Or for links pointing to pages where I can find a solution *(I spent a looot of time googling around...)*.

Luca

Note: I think it's useless to add here the HTML and JS code of the page in the router that generate the line **rn=MGyN4YpepJoE6kSXPVT9lgA%3D**, but if you need it, I can report it.

Answer (score 0):

Look careful at the captured data and you might notice that these data are not part of the header. The header ends with \r\n\r\n (Bytes 021b..021e) and your "session cookie" is not a cookie (which would be part of the header) but the body of the POST request.  Thus you need to use `--post-data 'rn=MGyN...'`

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Now I can't access the server (I'm using my laptop) but I'm sure that I've put the 'rn=…' stuff as POST data in my early trials with no luck (the router went to the auth page). Maybe there was some kind of error...♪ or putting the **'rn=…'** isn't enough to fool the router and make him think I'm using a browser. Anyway I will try as soon as possible.